# How to shutdown static threadpools?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, classloader, threadpool

I am developing application which creates new classloader, executes some code with classes loaded using this classloader and then throws it away, starting another classloader and doing the same. I would like to reclaim all memory and kill all threads left over one use of the classloader.

My problem is that if the code loaded by this classloader is poorly written (or rather not expecting this use), it can leave some threads behind. Current problem in one such library is that there is a threadpool that cannot be shut down, stored as final static variable (`shutdown()` checks whether this is the 'default' threadpool stored in this variable and fails if it is so). I know how to modify final variables, but there's the danger that the variable lookup has been already optimized out.

I can't even shoot those threads using `Thread.stop()` (I am fine with inconsistent state of anything loaded in the dying classloader) because the threadpool would recreate this thread. I don't want to rewrite the shutdown code using reflection, and I am also reluctant to nulling all fields and hoping that it will crash. Generally, I'd like to keep the 'hacks' at minimum.

I know this is problem for application servers undeploying the applications - is there any good solution?

Comment: The most reliable way of doing that is to fork a new JVM and kill it afterwards. This at least ensures a clean state- but also has considerably high overhead. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Not really, this is quite heavy-weight solution.